# The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [15.0.1,15.0.1], but resolves to 16.0.1

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I come across this problem when I connected my android app to firebase, when I connect it to firebase authentication it brings this error:

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies..

Please guide me on how to solve this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari)

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52979211/8034839

Answer (score 0):

Change your google service class path version`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'`