# The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. - f

Tags: android

those my dependencies, I tied  this : com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

but still having the same issue

```
 dependencies {
          implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
          // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
          implementation project(path: 'CordovaLib')
          implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
          implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.2'
          compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
          compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'
          compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
          compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.4'
          compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
          compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
          compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.1'
          compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.2'
          compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.2'
          compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
          compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
          compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
          compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
          compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+'
          compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
          compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.+'
          // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
        }
```

Comment: Your versions are somewhat random. Please try making all Firebase and Google play and Android Support libraries have the same versions per those groupings. For example, Ads cannot be version 17 while Analytics is only 16

Comment: there not even is any ads `17.0.0` as well as `google-services:4.1.0` does not belong there. `24.1.1+` also appears to be invalid. and most likely, this question is a dupe. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52980504/549372 ...just no upvotes, so I cannot vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the latest version for each dependencies, you can check what those are in the [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/)

Also you should use implementation instead of compile, it is being deprecated at the end of the year