# Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:[15.0.0, 16.0.0)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle, build.gradle

The project was working fine until two days ago when error occured abruptly. I am not sure how to solve it as I have done everything I can including reinstalling android studio and gradle.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:strict-version->matcher-plugin:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
>    Versions that do not match:
>        1.1.0
>        1.0.3
>        1.0.2
>        1.0.1
>        1.0.0
>    Required by:
>        project :app > com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.1.0'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // Whether to append a 0 "abi digit" to versionCode when only a single APK is build
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit')) {
        cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "../cordova-plugin-firebase/firechat-build.gradle"
apply from: "../onesignal-cordova-plugin/firechat-build-extras-onesignal.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
    //ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = project.ext.defaultCompileSdkVersion
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
    //ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = project.ext.defaultBuildToolsVersion
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = '../debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = '../release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit == null ? false : cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : defaultMinSdkVersion
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit=' + cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    //This code exists for Crosswalk and other Native APIs.
    //By default, we multiply the existing version code in the Android Manifest by 10 and
    //add a number for each architecture.  If you are not using Crosswalk or SQLite, you can
    //ignore this chunk of code, and your version codes will be respected.

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        flavorDimensions "default"

        productFlavors {
            armeabi {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
                }
            }
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
                }
            }
            arm64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86"]
                }
            }
            x86_64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)) {
        // This provides compatibility to the default logic for versionCode before cordova-android 5.2.0
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

/*
 * WARNING: Cordova Lib and platform scripts do management inside of this code here,
 * if you are adding the dependencies manually, do so outside the comments, otherwise
 * the Cordova tools will overwrite them
 */


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+"
    compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
    compile "com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
      if(['validateReleaseSigning', 'validateSigningRelease', 'validateSigningArmv7Release', 'validateSigningX76Release'].contains(task.name)) {
         promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
      }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
      google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="27.0.1" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/a/52979211/8034839

Comment: I am also facing same issue in long time  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076998/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsstrict-version-matcher-plugin1-1-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated all dependencies in my `package.json` and it worked. I have a feeling it could have been something connected to `firebase` as @Aydus-Matthew suggested here. @Aydus-Matthew could be right for those of you who read come here with the same problem. My advice would be to try his simple solution before mind. But since mine worked and I didn't try @Aydus-Matthew's, I will put the tick here.

Answer (score 3):

that `strict-version-matcher-plugin` error message is a bogus error message.

there probably is no [Google Services plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) in version `4.2.0` yet.

the actual problem is - that it has lost nothing in the `Java` dependencies, because those `buildscript` dependencies are `Gradle` plugins. therefore, replace:

```
compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
```

with:

```
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
```

and add it as the bottom line, instead:

```
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

add repository `google()` in the root-project `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

you could also update `com.android.tools.build:gradle` from version `3.0.1` to `3.2.1`. there are some more version number to update, because it should target API `28` with build-tools `28.0.3`. also think that with updated build-tools, `gradleVersion = "4.6.0"` would be required to build.

Comment: OP should also replace the rest of the `compile`s with `implementation` or `api`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Martin Zeitler. When I update `com.android.tools.build:gradle` from `3.0.1` to `3.2.1` I get this error:
[link](> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.). I have also tried to access the link directly in the browser but it's inaccessible.
I try(also did it several times before) to change the app\build.gradle dependencies but it always goes back to the original format after the build as I have shared above.

Comment: @PaulKitatta you need to add repository `google()`, also for the build-script.

Comment: OK I did everything but now am getting this error:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\Paul\frontend\whatsapp\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.
properties to gradle-4.6-all.zip

My gradle versing is 4.10.2 so I really don't understand this.

Comment: Adding a `repositories{google()}` section resolved my `Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.1 because no repositories are defined.` error, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and solve it by adding:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
   }
}
```

in `build.gradle` in the root folder of project.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was due to cordova-plugin-fcm. What worked for me was to open platforms/android/cordova-plugin-fcm/reporting-FCMPlugin.gradle and change this line
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'`
to
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

This issue suddenly appeared for us a few days ago too. If we remove cordova-plugin-firebase our builds are successful.

The only thing that worked for us was to update the cordova-plugin-firebase version in config.xml to

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="2.0.5" />
```

We use IonicPro for builds and can now successfully build both android and ios.

On our local PCs, we had to remove and re-create the /platforms/android folder.

Comment: Thanks for response. So doesn't you app need the plugin? because mine needs firebase for push notifications and stuff.

Comment: Yes! We've been working on a solution. Answer updated.

Comment: It seems your update missed what you actually updated to. 'The only thing that worked for us was to update the cordova-plugin-firebase version in config.xml to '  ...but no info on what you updated to .. ?

TIA!

Comment: Code now displays in answer. Had to format that line as code.

Comment: not worked in my case. can you please add some more details related to that @Aydus-Matthew