# Could not find com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.1.0

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.

Could not find com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.1.0.

Searched in the following locations: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.pom https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.jar file:/C:/Users/e1706396/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.pom file:/C:/Users/e1706396/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.jar Required by: unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

**plugin  are i am using**

```html
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-appavailability" spec="^0.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="^1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="^5.2.1">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="xxx" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.19" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mfp" spec="^8.0.2018070216" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mfp-push" spec="^8.0.2018040410" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-wheel-selector-plugin" spec="^1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="info.protonet.imageresizer" spec="^0.1.1" />
```

**Build gradle using**

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="27.0.1" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

dependency may be i think

### old or other system working fine

Node -v 3.10.10, 
NPM -v  6.10.10

### My current system note working getting error

npm -v 6.4.1, 
node -v 8.12.0
node -v

Answer (score 5):

I have had similar issue in Android Project on Android Studio.

Make sure that your project level build.gradle file is something like this

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Solved this issue by adding repositories with both jcenter() and google() in both repositories{} and allprojects{}

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR This is a problem related to jcenter repository reporting it's not finding the lib your plugins relies on, a lot of people is experiencing this same issue, In order to get it working you need to put jcenter as the last option in your `platforms/android/build.gradle` file.

From this: `platforms/android/build.gradle` - Line 40

```
// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

To this: `platforms/android/build.gradle` - Line 40

```
// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Then try building your app again.

If you get error related to not finding the `google()` repostiory, try updating your gradle version.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, caused by cordova-plugin-fcm.

Solved by add google maven to plugin's gradle.
For cordova-plugin-fcm, it is here:

> platforms > android > cordova-plugin-fcm > ***.gradle

You may check inside your cordova-plugin-googleplus folder or other plugin that have dependencies to google-services, mine look like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'
    ...
}
```

My final code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'
    }
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to the **build.gradle** repositories from the **cordova-support-google-services** plugin. The final file now looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

I'm using Gradle 4.1.