# Ionic Cordova run failure for "ionic cordova run android"

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I have an Ionic Cordova app that I have not touched in a few months. I wanted to make a small tweak to the app today and release it but when I did, I started having a dependency issue.

When I try to run 'ionic cordova run android' the build fails. Even without making any changes to the app (revert all changes and try to build what worked for the last APK) it still is failing. I have tried uninstalling the cordova intercom plugin and that changed nothing. I have also tried updating all of my npm packages and that did not help either.

This is the error log I get:

> cordova run android
>   Android Studio project detected
>   cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release: Android platform: cordova-android@7
>   cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release: No custom version found in config.xml - using plugin default
>   cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release: Android platform: cordova-android@7
>   cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release: No custom version found in config.xml - using plugin default
>   cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: cordova-android@7
>   cordova-android-support-gradle-release: No custom version found in config.xml - using plugin default
>   Preparing Firebase on Android
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Boogaloo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
>   studio
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   Subproject Path: app
>   publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
>   cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release: 15.0.0
>   cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release: 15.0.0
>   cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+
>   Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
>   The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
>           at build_8vin5yy2zwz3fxyzepqpp0rqu.run(C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\projects\myapp\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:151)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\projects\myapp\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-intercom\savings-build-extras-intercom.gradle' line: 71
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:compile'.
  >   Could not find com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:15.0.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app > com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
(node:3432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\projects\myapp\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-intercom\savings-build-extras-intercom.gradle' line: 71
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:compile'.
  >   Could not find com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:15.0.0.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        file:/C:/Users/Boogaloo/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.pom
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/15.0.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-15.0.0.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app > com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\projects\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:3432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3432) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

## Update

I tried updating the cordova android platform to 7.1.0 but it hasn't helped.
I can't seem to delete the cordova firebase plugin using the command

ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:\[15.0.0, 16.0.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073958/could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-google-android-gmsstrict-version-ma)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `cordova-plugin-firebase`?

If so,

run `ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase` and try building again.

If it works, `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase@2.0.5`

Comment: I tried to run that command and got another error:

'cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase --save
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-firebase from android
Android Studio project detected
missing file :: app/src/main
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
(node:5748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Uh oh!
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open'
'C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\projects\myapp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'

Comment: Try downgrading Android, to verifiy if it works. ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0

Comment: Just tried this now and I am still getting the same error

Comment: I've updated my android studio and now get this error 
> cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase --save
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-firebase from android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
(node:5876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Uh oh!
AndroidStudio.js:inAndroidStudioProject root does not exist: C:\Users\Boogaloo\WebstormProjects\IONIC\....

Comment: After > ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0
I get this error
>ionic cordova platform check
android @ unknown; current did not install, and thus its version cannot be determined