# Gradle error after upgrading to AndoidX the latest Android Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, guava, androidx

After upgrading to the latest AndroidX libs & Android Gradle Plugin, when I run lint on my project, the lint build failed.

It all started with the latest Android Gradle Plugin complaining that Program type already present:com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture when building my project

Below are the errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.guava:guava' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android'
           Dependency path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android'
           Dependency path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-guava:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android'
           Dependency path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.25.0' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
           Dependency path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android'
           Constraint path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava' strictly '23.6-android' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 23.6-android
           Constraint path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava' strictly '23.6-android' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 23.6-android
           Constraint path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava' strictly '23.6-android' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 23.6-android
           Constraint path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:guava' strictly '23.6-android' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 23.6-android

   > Could not resolve org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.3'
           Dependency path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.2'
           Dependency path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.3'
           Constraint path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Constraint path 'Code Base:app:unspecified' --> 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0

   > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

I tried putting the following but it doesn't work:

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {

        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'failureaccess'


        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }

            if('guava' == details.requested.name) {
                details.useVersion '27.0-android'
            }

        }
    }
}
```

May I know what the errors mean and how can I solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a lint error per se. Lint is just trying to compile all your modules and tests and you are getting a dependency conflict on Guava. I updated some of your original question.

Answer (score 5):

Check that you don't have duplicated dependencies for variants. For instance:

```
implementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42' 
...
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also trying to solve this, for me it's due to the new Google places library:

`implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0"`

which was causing tests under `androidTest` to fail.

As a workaround, I added this to `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
    androidTestImplementation.exclude module: 'guava'
    androidTestImplementation.exclude module: 'error_prone_annotations'
    androidTestImplementation.exclude module: 'checker-qual'
}
```

which fixes both lint and Android tests. Not sure of the consequences yet though.

edit: In your case you might have to put `checker-compat-qual` instead of `checker-qual`

Comment: Hi limdale, thanks for your great help.
Your solution works for me to solve my android testing errors.
For those who meet the same errors as me...eventually I put this in my build.gradle

configurations {
    androidTestImplementation.exclude module: 'guava'
    androidTestImplementation.exclude module: 'error_prone_annotations'
    androidTestImplementation.exclude module: 'checker-compat-qual'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}

Answer (score 0):

change

```
details.useVersion '27.0-android'
```

to

```
details.useVersion '23.6-android'
```

Because of error message `Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android.` tells it requires version `23.6-android`

Comment: Please close current question and post a separate question for a new error if it is not related to current post. I will go to the new thread to take a look. Thanks

Comment: **Hi, thanks for the reply. I have tried and created another new set of errors:**

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lint'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[17.0.4].
     Required by ...
   > **Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.3.0].**
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7 >
  
** How to solve the above errors? **

Comment: See this thread about [google play services version issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52979211/8034839)

Comment: Update: after I have cleared the cache, clean the project and run the above answer again (i.e. change to 23.6-android), I get back the original errors, still saying ... Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android.

Answer (score 0):

Put this on Build.gradle in app module

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
```

Comment: This is not a lint issue, it's a dependency conflict